# How can I inject a if statement in an HTML attribute?

Tags: if-statement, go, conditional-statements, go-templates, go-html-template

I'm trying to create a go html (Go 1.13) [with a context](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) {{.}}.

I've managed to display context variables as div values, but I can't find the right way to put context variables inside HTML attributes.

For instance, this code works:

```
{{ if .AppCtx.Title }} 
<a href="/">{{ .AppCtx.Title }}</a>
{{end}}
```

But this does not seem to work :

```
<a href="{{ if .AppCtx.Link }}{{.AppCtx.Link}} {{end}}">
```

I' ve tried different syntaxes :

- single quotes :

```
<a href='{{ if .AppCtx.Link }}{{.AppCtx.Link}} {{end}}'>
```

- double quotes in front of the conditional statement:

```
<a href=""{{ if .AppCtx.Link }}{{.AppCtx.Link}} {{end}}>
```

- double quotes around :

```
<a href="{{ if .AppCtx.Link }}{{.AppCtx.Link}} {{end}}">
```

I've read https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/ but didn't find any clue in it.

Comment: What does "But this does not seem to work" mean?

Comment: What you said did not work should work. What did it do?

Comment: @Peter my condition is true, but once compiled, my html only displays <a href>

Comment: Based on that output, `AppCtx.Link` is nil or empty

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/_Q-3VAhHn45

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot ! The issue must be somewhere else ; I'm looking into it. Now I know my syntax in gohtml is not the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do this instead?

```
<a href="{{ if .AppCtx.Title}}{{.AppCtx.Title}} {{end}}">
```